# How to convert UInt16 into Integer

Tags: bit-manipulation, swift4

I am facing issue with conversion, I have 2 UInt8 byte and converted as UInt16 by using

```
 let testLiveSpeed : UInt16
 let bytes: [UInt8] = [data[3], data[4]] //where data has contain array of `UInt8`, 
 self.testLiveSpeed = UnsafePointer(bytes).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self, capacity: 1) {
      $0.pointee
 }
```

But  `self.testLiveSpeed` it give unsigned Integer value , but i want signed Int value. Please help

Comment: The `U` in `UInt16` stands for *unsigned*. What do you expect?

Comment: singed Int Value @vadian

Comment: *signed Int* is `Int16` like in the answer.

Comment: yes , i want Int16 byte formate

Comment: Is the answer not work for you? I changed the UInt16 to Int16 as you need Int16 result.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
let  testLiveSpeed : Int16
let data: [UInt8] = [1, 1, 1, 127, 255]
let bytes: [UInt8] = [data[3], data[4]] 
testLiveSpeed = UnsafePointer(bytes).withMemoryRebound(to: Int16.self, capacity: 1) {
            $0.pointee
        }
print(testLiveSpeed);
```